# Excel Conditional Formatting with Two Conditions

Tags: excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am trying to format a row to change color based on the value of the cells at the end of the row. For whatever reason, Excel is forcing the `Applies to` to contain additional `$` and the cells are not highlighting in any logical way.

Here is what I am trying to do:

- If Column I = Yes & Column J = Yes -> Row "Fill Color" is Green
- If Column I = No & Column J = Yes -> Row "Fill Color" is Orange
- If Column I = No & Column J = No -> Row "Fill Color" is Red

The formulas I am using are as follows:

- `=OR(I$3<>"Yes",J$3<>"Yes")` Format: `Fill Red` Applies to `=A$3:D$3`
- `=OR(I$3="No",J$3<>"Yes")` Format: `Fill Orange` Applies to `=A$3:D$3`
- `=OR(I$3="Yes",J$3="Yes")` Format: `Fill Green` Applies to `=A$3:D$3`

Excel keeps changing the Applies to to be `=A$3:$D$3` and even though I keeping changing it to `=A$:D$3` I can't seem to find why.

Currently, here is the behavior I am seeing:

- Column A is `Orange` and columns B-D are staying `Red` when I & J are `Yes`
- Columns A-D are `Red` when and J is `No` regardless of what column I is
- Columns A-D do not turn `Green` in with any combination

Am I missing something really simple? I can't seem to figure out why it would work this way.

Comment: I'm not following where Columns A and B-D suddenly showed up from  when your initial description is for columns I and J. Also - you mentioned the following `A$:D$3` - that should not be possible because the `$1` needs to precede something, did you mistype that?

Comment: I was trying to find a balance between being succinct and having a wall of text you could see from space. Let me go into a little more detail...

So I have Columns A-J on my sheet. 

The first two rows are just headers, so the information does not show up until row 3.

Columns E-H are usually blank as they are only applicable to about half the rows on the sheet.

The problem I am having is that originally, Column I was just a Yes/No column, so I was conditionally formatting A-D  based on whether Column I was Yes or No.

Comment: When I added a second column, it seemed to create a bunch of weird problems. I was trying to make it so that if Column I was "No" but Column J was "Yes," then it would be a third, different color than I was using when I only had Column I. The problem(s) seem to be that Excel is adding another $ to the formula and I am not sure if that is causing the problem or not as well as an issue where the original formatting I had for columns A-D in relation to Column I doesn't work now that I have tried to add column J and how the cells are being hightlighed does not seem to match the formulas I have.

Comment: I am not sure if that makes sense or not. I trying to be as straightforward on the formatting formula, and the desired result, as I could be.

Answer (score 0):

Two things...

**$ Sign**

I believe the $ behavior you are seeing is normal...  The formulas can be relative or absolute cells, but the ranges to which the rules apply should not be and would not have any reason to be.

**Logic**

I believe your logic problem will be embarrassingly obvious once you step back for a moment and look at your formulas.  In your text version of your logic you describe your logical condition as AND().  That is, `if I is <> "yes" AND J is <> "yes"`.  But take a look at your formulas.

You didn't enter:

```
=AND(I$3<>"Yes",J$3<>"Yes")
```

but rather you entered:

```
=OR(I$3<>"Yes",J$3<>"Yes")
```

Change `OR` to `AND` and I suspect you are back in business.

Comment: I cleared all formatting rules and set I & J to "Yes." Then I added the formula for `=AND` which made C & D Red but A & B have no formatting whatsoever. Then I added the rule for `OR` with the `AND` rule and now A-C are Orange and D has no formatting.
I still think that Excel forcing "applies to" to change from absolute to relative is the culprit, but I can't figure out how to turn it off. When I double-checked the formula for each column, it changed relative to the column (e.g. even though A linked to I & J, B linked to J & K). I think I have to do 1 column at a time if I can't fix this.

Comment: I think I have a workaround until I finish sorting this out.

I changed the formulas to the following:
• `=AND(I3="Yes",J3="Yes")` Makes the cell Green
• `=AND(I3<>"Yes",J3<>"Yes")` Makes the cell Red
• `=AND(I3<>"Yes",J3="Yes")` Makes the cell Orange

Now, if I set this to column A, and then use the Format Painter to include other cells in just column A, they all highlight properly, setting the "Applies to" to `=$A$3:$A$12`

However, if I then "Format Painter" to column B, C, or D, it just goes all over the place.

Comment: The $ becomes very important in the *formula* portion of the rule.  You probably want `$I3` in your formulas.  If you use `I3` and apply your rule to column A, then applying the same conditional format to column B, whether by copy/paste, fill, or format painter will result in column B’s format depending in the value of J3, not I3.  You have to be very deliberate about locking the columns in your conditions.