# Conditional Format with 4 Conditions

Tags: conditional-statements, format, countif, multiple-conditions

I'm looking to create a formula that I can put within Conditional Formatting that allows me to highlight either an entire row, or Column A (Job ID), when four conditions are met. As shown in the example below, I have 3 row entries where Row 2 has unique values (the only thing that match are the Job ID), however, Rows 3 & 4 all share identical values within columns A B C D.

Essentially, the goal is to identify if a Candidate with an identical name shares the same Job ID, Job Title and "workflow stage name", so that I can potentially eliminate duplicate entries.

[Image of sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3Q6D.png)

I tried to run a countifs formula, but was unsure of how to do it across datasets with over 20,000 rows.

Comment: Does this helps you?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74567309/excel-conditional-formatting-with-two-conditions